# Shaping EF LINQ Query Results Using Multi-Table Includes

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I have a simple LINQ EF query below using the method syntax.  I'm using my Include statement to join  four tables: Event and Doc are the two main tables, EventDoc is a many-to-many link table, and DocUsage is a lookup table.

My challenge is that I'd like to shape my results by only selecting specific columns from each of the four tables.  But, the compiler is giving a compiler is giving me the following error:

'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection does not contain a definition for "Doc' and no extension method 'Doc' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection' could be found.

I'm sure this is something easy but I'm not figuring it out.  I haven't been able to find an example of someone using the multi-table include but also shaping the projection.

Thx,Mark

```
var qry= context.Event
    .Include("EventDoc.Doc.DocUsage")
    .Select(n => new
    {
        n.EventDate,
        n.EventDoc.Doc.Filename,  //<=COMPILER ERROR HERE
        n.EventDoc.Doc.DocUsage.Usage
    })
    .ToList();

    EventDoc ed;
    Doc d = ed.Doc;  //<=NO COMPILER ERROR SO I KNOW MY MODEL'S CORRECT
    DocUsage du = d.DocUsage;
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult to know what is going on without a screencap of your model, including the navigational properties on each entity.

But if your saying it's a many-to-many between **Event** and **Doc** (with **EventDoc** being the join table), and assuming your join table has nothing but the FK's and therefore doesn't need to be mapped, then shouldn't a single **Event** have *many* **Doc**'s?

This query:

`var query = ctx.Event.Include("EventDoc.Doc"`);

Would imply (based on the lack of pluralization): **a single Event has a single EventDoc which has a single Doc.**

But shouldn't that be:  **a single Event has a single EventDoc which has many Doc's.**

Therefore your projection doesn't really make sense. Your trying to project to an anonymous type, with *EventDate* and *Filename* for a single Doc, but an Event has **many** Docs.

Maybe a projection like this would be more suitable:

```
var query = ctx.Event.Include("EventDoc.Docs.DocUsage")
                     .Select(x => new
                     {
                        EventDate = x.EventDate,
                        DocsForEvent = x.EventDocs.Docs
                     }).ToList();
```

And for that you work you need to fix up your model. Im surprised it even validates/compiles.

Either your model is wrong or your description of the database cardinalities in your question is. :)

Of course, i could be completely misunderstanding your database and/or model - so if i am let me know and i'll remove this answer.

Comment: This is very true.  You may even need `.Include("EventDocs.Docs.DocUsage")` if each event has multiple `EventDoc` objects.

Comment: yep, true. let's see what the OP says before we cast more stones. :)

Comment: RPM - hey thanks for the post on a Sunday nite!  And thx for not casting stones, I understand that you don't know my model.  Yes, this is truly a many-to-many in my model.  The user has many docs, and for a given event they could choose to associate 0 or many of their docs with any one of their events.

Comment: Regarding the syntax that you posted, that still doesn't compile for me.  The big problem is that the compiler won't recognize any relationships beyond one table away from Event.  It accepts x.EventDoc in the projection, but not x.EventDoc.Doc.

Comment: @sisdog - i see, "EventDoc" is your join table. Couple of queries. 1) Why do you have "DocId" in the join table? If you remove this field, then things will be **a hell of a lot easier**, because the join table won't need to be mapped, and you can do `ctx.Event.Include("Docs")`. 2) On "Event" entity, you have "EventDoc" navigation. This should be "EventDocs" (plural), to handle the "many" EventDocs.

Comment: @RPM1984 - since my EventDoc table exists to represent a many-to-many relationship it obviously needs to have a FK to my Doc table (DocID) and a FK to my Event table (EventID).  You might be recommending (?) simplifying my link table (EventDoc) so that it only contains two fields, EventID and DocID.  I agree, this will cause the EF Model Wizard to remove the EventDoc table from my model and give me the direct navigation you described. But, what if I plan to add other fields to my link table, like, say,  AddDate.  Then I'm back to my original question right?

Comment: @sisdog, no - you can leave the extra field on the join table. it just means you have to do a nested include. Your current issue is you have a 0..1 - * between Event and EventDoc (look at designer), but a navigational called "EventDoc" on EventDoc, which is implying it's a singular. How is that declared on your model, is it a ICollection<EventDoc>?